# Rails Update multiple records. How to check which one is failed to update

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord

```
params[:user_ids] = [1,2,3,4]
users = User.where(id: params[:user_ids]).update_all(:status => "DEACTIVATE")
users.blank?
```

Trying updating multiple records at once, But in some cases id not found or any other reasons `status` column not get updated.

So how to get all the ID, Where its failed to update the records.

Answer (score 0):

Actually there is `no way` to track failed record with `update_all` method.
as this method ignore model validation and Active Record callbacks.

read [this](https://apidock.com/rails/ActiveRecord/Relation/update_all)

And `.where` ignore `ids that not present error` and return blank array if no record found.